# MySQL Update query is not working with and operator

Tags: mysql

First query:

```
update tableA set columnA = 'Hello' and updated_at = now() where id = 10;
```

Second query:

```
update tableA set columnA = 'Hello', updated_at = now() where id = 10;
```

When I execute first query columnA updated as 0, where as second query worked fine and updated as Hello.

Why first query update the table as 0 value.

Comment: In `set columnA = 'Hello', updated_at = now()` you have two separate assigning expressions. In `set columnA = 'Hello' and updated_at = now()` you have one assigning expression, second `=` symbol is comparing operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that MySQL's lax syntax is at work here.  Consider rewriting your first update as:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET columnA = ('Hello' AND updated_at = NOW())
WHERE id = 10;
```

That is, the expression on the RHS being assigned to `columnA` is actually the `AND` of a string literal, and an assignment.  Check the demo below to verify that this RHS in fact is evaluating to zero.

### Demo

As to exactly *why* this is happening, we would have to lookup MySQL's rules for what happens.  But best practice is to just stick with your second update query, which uses correct ANSI syntax.

Comment: Yes. `updated_at = NOW()` gives 0 (FALSE). `'Hello' AND 0` gives 0 (non-empty string is treated as TRUE which is an alias of 1).

Answer (score 1):

@TimBiegeleisen is right, there is only one assigning expression for your first query.

MySQL syntax for `SET assignment_list` in UPDATE  is like

```
 assignment [, assignment] ...
```

every assigning expression for column separated by comma(,)

So, when you have multiple assignment use comma(,) to separate the assignment.

You found more details doc [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)